# Career Information

Tags: career

I am currently studying Forensic Psychology but have had a slight change in what I would like to do as a career. I would like to move over into the world of cyber crime / security.

I was wondering if anyone could give any advice on what I should try and educate myself on from home to aid and back up my degree for when I finish university.

I am already trying to teach myself HTML / CSS and have done an online course of Intro to Cyber Security.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Melissa

Comment: @Aria you should throw that all into an answer.

Comment: @INV3NT3D Actually, no (although they've done it now already, so the point is moot). Answering questions that are textbook off-topic is generally frowned upon - it encourages people to ask more off-topic questions. I trust that Aria has the best of intentions, but it's not something we generally advise.

Comment: @S.L.Barth Noted, my apologies.

Answer (score 1):

I think with CSS and HTML you are on good track, have a look on PHP, Java, Python, Ruby on Rails, JavaScript, C#. I think that's the way to learn computing and with this you will learn security. The computing comes first the security second. To have a grasp of computing it's good to learn how at least one dev stack based on Java, PHP etc works and how to secure it. Then go with the cloud - AWS, Google Cloud, Azure, architecture, best practice etc. You need to know both Linux and Windows Server (cloud can give you test environments). And the databases including cloud ones.

And then, source code control like Git or SVN (good to know), ^*PKI*^, monitoring (like Solar Winds, Nagios), self-service helpdesk like Rundeck (to have layered password change for example is important).

In cloud you can learn CDNs, VLANs (not the same as on real switch but it'ss something), DNS and so on. With understanding of these you can learn the security challenges. And there's also big subject of InfoSec in companies, so these corporate firewalls (in cloud you can provision some), Windows Group Policy, secure office storage, in programming it's secure API.

Finally you can make Computer Networking certification. Understanding networks as well software is somewhat critical for real understanding of any kind of security. Secondly to understand how PKI and policing the companies is another essential thing. Basically how to properly handle crypto and how to force employees not to spill the keys and data is another essential thing, like how to minimize leakage of information by segmenting network, restricting and properly managing access, forcing AV software, updates and so on - true essentials.

So understanding of the current technology, also mobiles and tablets, will give you what you need for the security.
There are many courses in Cyber Security and InfoSec but without understanding underlying technology this is very often not leading to anything effective.

It's the common sense which is most previous and you can't have one without understanding underlying technology.

Also the most common issue with InfoSec and Cyber-Security is that they do not integrate well with the rest of the company. So it's good to know what Network Monitoring is for as this is also major component of the overall security. And how to protect the source code from accessing and tampering is also very important. And how to do the self-service for change password of custom applications when the domain controller is not involved. These things are sometimes critical for the corporations to live. The corporate information theft is so common today and in most instances they never realized nor detected it, only after close, careful investigation (which most external specialized companies don't do when they say otherwise), it turns out that half of the employees are browsing HR data, which is failure on every layer of information defense.

Also automation is something very important. Whatever it's automated network scan, vulnerability scan and so on, is something what most companies do overlook a lot, or when they perform is really cheap and poor.

And also remember that security of the company is very often not the result of the specific InfoSec or Cyber-Security departments but result of their good IT / Software Dev management. The Security depts usually eat whatever the former two cooked in advance and they can make it a bit better or a bit worse. So it does not depend on how good InfoSec dept. is, but how much respect from other departments they have as well, and what InfoSec was able to promote on their own too.